# Is Diablo 3 open for mods?

Tags: diablo-iii, mods

I'm wondering if Diablo 3 is open to the creation of mods/custom maps?

Not if Blizzard is supporting it, but do the game files have hooks and stuff that a mod could hook on?

Comment: Well, most games can be modded if you have the time and know how.

Comment: The question could be reformulated as "Does D3 have an API for Mods?"

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic.  The question 'is (x game) available for modding' could be asked of any game, ever. Those kinds of questions are ones we tend to shy away from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Blizzard said they have no official support for modifying the game, and doing that yourself is against the Terms of Service and could lead to your account getting removed.

In addition, because of the client-server nature of the game, there is a severe limitation on what one can change anyway.