# Can you change the game's sound effects?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Diablo 3 open for mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66822/is-diablo-3-open-for-mods)

Are the sound effects used by the various abilities stored on your computer? Is there any way to replace them with a custom sound effect?

I know this sounds silly, but I am trying to replace (as a joke for a friend) the [Wave of Light](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/wave-of-light) sound effect with the Taco Bell sound effect.

Comment: The post you actually want is here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67771/how-can-i-make-my-follower-cut-it-out-with-all-the-jibber-jabber The topic to research to accomplish this is"MPQ file overriding"

Comment: P.S. I your quest to add the Taco Bell sound effect is a noble one; I salute you!